# VS 2012 change DEFAULT debugging 'Working Directory'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-debugging

Changing the working directory inside the debugging project options dialog results in an entry added to the "Project User Options File". This file is not 'checked in' to our source control repository because it is supposed to be user specific. I need to change the default setting for the Debugging Working Directory option so users who check out this project don't have to continually change it before they can launch the debugger.

I had thought that moving that generated setting entry from the 'Project User Options File' to the 'Project File' would be sufficient. It does work - as in the default working directory changes - BUT then I can no longer debug the project from inside VS. When trying to run the debugger, all I get is a dialog box saying that VS is unable to start the debugger. (Looking at the debugging settings they seem fine and unchanged).

So what is the correct way to set a default debugging working directory for a VS project?

NOTE: The dialog box only appears if you 'MOVE' the setting entry from the User Options File to the Project File. If you just copy the entry - so that it is in both files - there is no problems running the debugger. Unfortunately this means, again, the user still has to add the setting manually.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to set a default debugging working directory for a VS project. Each user must do that on his own. Here is a related question/answer, but it explores the pitfalls more than providing a good solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079128/changing-the-debugging-working-directory-globally-not-per-user-in-vs2008

Comment: I would set the working directory inside the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a post checkout script to manually add this line to the file.

if the file is not stored you can't go away of manually editing it before usage.

How many times the users are checking out your project? think about the amount of time you will spend on this activity versus the actual usage of it