# Visual Studio 2019 Project Working Directory Setting Not Stored in GitHub Repo

Tags: visual-studio, github

On Computer A I create a Visual C++ solution and project with some code, then commit it to GitHub. On Computer B I clone it and open up the solution file in Visual Studio on both computers. Both computers are running Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019.

On Computer A the Working Directory for the project in `Configuration Properties\Debugging\Working Directory` is `$(SolutionDir)`, which is correct. On Computer B it is `$(ProjectDir)`, which is wrong.

[image: Property Pages Dialog Box]

GitHub Desktop reports that both repos are up-to-date. This tells me that Visual Studio's Working Directory setting isn't stored in the project file, but maybe someplace that is listed in GitHub's standard `.gitignore` for Visual Studio (since `$(ProjectDir)` is the default Working Directory for Visual Studio).

GitHub's Visual Studio `.gitignore` is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/VisualStudio.gitignore). To this I have added:

```
desktop.ini
*/[Dd]oxygen/html/
.editorconfig
*.exe
```

So is the Working Directory stored in the hidden (and .gitignored) `.vs` folder? Regardless, how do I get the Working Directory setting to be `$(SolutionDir)` for all clones?

Needless to say, a Google search for this information was less than enlightening.

Comment: Seems to have been answered previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5313972/33051 - it's a per user setting by default, however you can move it into a shared user file and commit that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the "debugging / working directory" globally (not per-user) in VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079128/changing-the-debugging-working-directory-globally-not-per-user-in-vs2008)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5313972/33051 no longer works, because the default user file is now `PROJECT.vcproj.user`. It doesn't save it as `PROJECT.vcproj.COMPUTERNAME.USER.user` (I'm using Visual Studio 2022)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. In summary, all I needed to do was to remove the line `*.user` from the `.gitignore`.

Comment: Generally speaking though you should not be tracking user-specific settings files in a git repository. You should let each "user" of your repo define those settings as they wish locally. I should be able to choose my working directory as `D:/repos/foo/` if I want to, and not interfere with anyone else's ability to choose their own path.